# Guidlines on meshes and image textures

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all, are there general guidelines for images used as textures for collada files?

I have a faint recollection that these images are supposed to be square and maybe also have dimensions that are powers of 2 (e.g. 64x64, 512x512, etc.).. I also know that small is better from a memory/speed concern.. but what are the practical guidelines that should be followed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4965/guidlines-on-meshes-and-image-textures/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 319 on 2013-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You are correct on all accounts. The textures should be square and powers of two. Smaller is also more efficient.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0